# Identify the Max Value in a New Column and Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, group-by, max

I am beginner to Python and am having some trouble trying to solve a problem. I am able to get to this point. What I need to do from here is create `top_team` column and store a `1` there if they have the highest `score`.  Every other team would be assigned a `0`  I would also like to be able to loop through this `x` number of times and store all previous results/summarize.

```
  import pandas as pd
    
    data = {'team': ['ATL', 'ATL', 'BOS', 'BOS', 'NYY', 'NYY'], 'player': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']}
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    import scipy.stats as stats
    
    a, b = 0, 9999
    mu = 5
    sigma = 1
    dist = stats.truncnorm((a - mu) / sigma, (b - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
    
    data['score'] = dist.rvs(6).round(2)
    
    grouped = data.groupby("team", as_index=True)["score"].sum()
    grouped = pd.DataFrame(grouped)
    grouped = grouped.reset_index(level=0)
    
    print(grouped)
```

The above code yields a result similar to this:

```
   team  score
0  ATL  10.73
1  BOS  12.20
2  NYY   9.75
```

In this example, `BOS` would be the `top_team` and be assigned a value of `1` in the new column.

I would like to be able to turn this into a function and run this `x = 10` times and end up with a result similar to the below. Obviously, results would vary dependent upon the random number generation.

```
    team  top_team
0   ATL    4
1   BOS    1
2   NYY    5
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case one of the easiest way to keep and update information about best team is using `dict()`

I would solve it the following way:

```
import scipy.stats as stats

def get_top_team(data):
    
    data = data.copy()
    a, b = 0, 9999
    mu = 5
    sigma = 1
    dist = stats.truncnorm((a - mu) / sigma, (b - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)

    data['score'] = dist.rvs(6).round(2)
    
    grouped = data.groupby("team", as_index=True)["score"].sum()
    grouped = pd.DataFrame(grouped)
    grouped = grouped.reset_index(level=0)
    
    return grouped.loc[grouped.score.idxmax, 'team']


res = {}

for i in range(10):
    best_team = get_top_team(data)
    res[best_team] = res.get(best_team, 0) + 1
```

And in case you need to get a result as a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(res.items(), columns = ['team', 'top_team'])
```

Comment: I am getting the error `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` when trying this.